# Trouble passing session variable into mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having a bit of trouble passing a session variable into a mysql query in php.
Tried putting it into a variable and testing against that and no luck.
Also tried various formatting already. At a loss. It's just a simple string passed in.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback  WHERE StudentID=" . $_SESSION['BCode'] . "");
```

Comment: `session_start()` at the top of your file?

Comment: (probable) Combination of both answers below.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 3):

Are you setting:

```
session_start();
```

at the header of your .php file?

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

$studentid = $_SESSION['BCode'];

$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE StudentID='" . $studentid . "'"); 

$finalResult = array(); 

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
    $finalResult[] = $row; 
} 

$jsonoutput = json_encode($finalResult); // Encodes the query result into JSON 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `session_start();` and try

```
mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE StudentID='" . $_SESSION['BCode'] . "'");
```

Comment: <?php
session_start();
mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE StudentID='" . $_SESSION['BCode'] . "'");
$finalResult = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $finalResult[] = $row;
}
  $jsonoutput = json_encode($finalResult); // Encodes the query result into JSON
?>

Comment: Now it's jumping down to the while loop. Error

Comment: You really should post full code right away when it comes to issues like this. @user3078580 This is the classic **"Can of Worms"** scenario.